# PHP POST not adhering to .htaccess server CORS policy

Tags: php, post

I am trying to set up a sandbox API for development, so users can hit the API from local dev machines.  But am running into what I believe is a CORS issue.

At first all traffic was being blocked by the CORS policy, so I added the following to my `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

After that, I can see that not only am I getting a 200 status, but my payload is being correctly sent.  Good stuff!

[image]
[image]

However ..  The PHP file that is requesting -> `/myp/index.php` contains ONLY the following:

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST);
echo "Done";
```

And the response from the above POST comes back:

```
Array
(
)
Done
```

I have read MANY posts that all say the same thing:  Add the following to the PHP file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept");
header ("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-JSON");
```

But when I add that to the PHP file .. I get another CORS error..

**WITH CORS RULES APPLIED TO PHP FILE**
[image]

What else do I need to be looking at? Why is CORS denied when I throw the PHP headers in, but is OK without them?  And why does PHP not accept the POST variables when CORS shows a `200` and I can verify post data sent?

Comment: `Why is CORS denied when I throw the PHP headers in`...the error hints at why - you're duplicating headers which htaccess has already set.

Comment: `And why does PHP not accept the POST variables`...this has nothing to do with CORS at all. It looks like you're sending JSON rather than standard form-url-encoded data. PHP doesn't parse that into $_POST. Take a look at [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: @ADyson OK .. That makes sense ..  Any insight as to why POST data is being rejected, but the page itself is rendering?

Comment: I just added a second comment already to explain that. See also the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for you input @ADyson!  I am going to accpt the answer below, since the API is already built out to accept POST queries .. The receiving JSON question doesn't help much .. But the solution to convert the data before being sent, does in fact answer my question ..

Comment: Well if you've already built it on the assumption of reading $_POST data then that makes sense. But if you're doing this in future, then it's pretty trivial to get it to read the JSON into a PHP variable, as that link I posted shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And the response from the above POST comes back:

The key there is that you do get the response and you don’t get a CORS error.

So the problem isn’t CORS and you shouldn’t touch your CORS headers.

(When you add the headers with PHP, Apache merges them with the headers you tell it to add and you end up with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, *` which, as the error message says, is invalid).

---

If the $_POST superglobal is empty, it is because you aren’t POSTing data in a format that PHP will decode automatically.

Most likely, you are sending a JSON payload in which case you need to either [read the body from STDIN and parse it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) or change the data you are sending to be in a format that PHP does support (URL Encoded or Multipart Encoded).

```
const body = new URLSearchParams({ foo: 1, bar: "hello, world" });
const url = "http://example.com";
const response = await fetch(url, { body });
```

Comment: I personally like the conversion of data before it's sent, is why I accepted this question .. As the API is already built out to accept POST data .. Will accept in 2 mins, Thank you!